# Python database dynamic visualization

Tags: jquery, python, html, visualization

My python script is simply gathering and storing some data with SQLite. I would like to visualize this data in the really simplest possible way, for example by using single HTML page. The database is dynamically updated to I need the page to be dynamically updated also, for example by using jQuery.

Is it somehow possible to call JS function from python script to update layout?
Is there any better but still simple way to that? Maybe some other visualization tools?

Comment: Would need to know more about the type of data and the type of visualizations you want.

Comment: Some status data about connected devices, it is frequently updated, so I need to manage database of these devices and dynamically update layout. I will simply need some table of devices and their status info, handle data updated so it will be visible to the user.
It would be really easy with jQuery I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a lot of data, you could use [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) to generate the html for the site and regenerate it either on an interval or on every change.

If you want it to look a bit nicer (with search and sorting), you can instead use a static HTML page with [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) [ajax loading](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) and generate the required JSON in your script. This would also allow you to make the site live-update the data (`dt.ajax.reload()`).

If you have a lot of entries (more than a few hundred rows), DataTables [server-side processing](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) would be better. For the ajax endpoint, I'd recommend a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) app with the [datatables library](https://github.com/orf/datatables/).

Comment: Thank you a lot. Datatables library can actually be a good choice